# What's the best approach for dynamically loading an editor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm still fairly new to ASP.NET MVC (or at least when it comes to using it in a more advanced scenarios) - so I'm looking for some feedback for a particular usage scenario and the best approach to implementing it. I have tried doing a number of searches - but have not found anything similar.

I'm quiet flexible on the approaches to implementing it - as long as the proposed solution works well.

Say, I have an entity called `Vehicle`, it is associated with an entity `VehicleType` and the `Vehicle` is also associated with an properties entity with is specific based on  the `VehicleType` called `VehicleProperties`. For example - Vehicle types can be "Car", "Boat" etc and the VehicleProperties contain "BodyStyle", "Color" etc for the Car VehicleType and "Length", "Weight" etc for the "Boat" VehicleType

On the create and edit forms for the `VehicleConntroller` I'm looking to do something along these lines: Have a drop down list of vehicle types and when the selection of that changes load the appropriate "VehicleProperties" form that is specific to this VehicleType.

This is where my question comes in - what is the best approach to this in MVC? Looking for an AJAX type approach. If anyone has any example tutorials or articles that would outline a potential solution - I would most appreciate it!

I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC 5 with jQuery - but willing to add other JS libraries if required for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here,

1.Create a strongly typed view and create a action method for the view which returns collections of VehicleType i.e List < VehicleType >

2.So you can create a DropDownlist in the view by iterating through the model using  html tag. In your case the model is "List < VehicleType > "

3.Create a strongly typed partial view, type of VehicleProperties.

4.Create another action method with a parameter that will return the partial view with appropriate VehicleProperties;

5.Write a onchange java script function for the DropDownlist. Call the action method through jQuery Ajax with selected dropdown value as a parameter.

6.The response of the ajax call will be html content which you can append to a html div.

Done..!! Happy Coding..!!